# Atom menu is missing. How do I re-enable

Tags: windows, text, atom-editor

The menu in Atom text editor is gone. I dont know how I disabled it. I tried F1-12 keys. How do I re enable it? Here's how it's looking now:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it covered by any of [these shortcuts](https://github.com/nwinkler/atom-keyboard-shortcuts)?

Comment: No, the menu is normally on the top. When I say menu im referring to the bar that has "File, edit, view, ect."

Comment: Ctrl+shift+P then search for it in settings!

Comment: See also [... How do I re-enable the **tools-menu**?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45661831/287948)

Comment: There are multiple issues with the menu-bar in electron: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/10297

Comment: Oh, my GOSH, this helped me fix not only my immediate mistake in Atom, but allowed me to go back and fix my layout problems with Sublime Text 3!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 175):

Open Atom and press ALT key you are done.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: @DavidPostill the answer above *does* work as a solution as I had the same issue (I disabled it on purpose, but was stuck in atom-vim mode so other hotkeys were overridden), albeit the isn't permanent. NickSamudae: after you depress ALT the menu will appear, then go into View -> Toggle Menu Bar to make it stay.

Comment: In Atom 1.8.0 on Ubuntu Linux pressing ALT *toggles* the menu, so for me this answered the question perfectly.

Answer (score 78):

**Temporarily show Menu Bar on ATOM:**

Press `ALT` Key to make the Menu bar appear but it is not permanent.

**Always display the Menu Bar on ATOM:**

To make the change permanent, press `ALT + V` and then select `Toggle Menu Bar` option from the "**View**" drop-down down.

> [Tested on ATOM running on Ubuntu 16.04]

Answer (score 31):

Press <kbd>Alt + v</kbd> and select Toggle menu bar option.

Answer (score 17):

Get cursor on top, where white header with file name, then press Alt.
**To set top menu by default always visible.** 
You needed in top menu selected:
FILE -> Config... -> autoHideMenuBar: true (change it to autoHideMenuBar: false)
Save it.

Answer (score 13):

Open atom editor and then press **Alt** and menu bar will appear. Now click on **View** tab and then click on **Toggle Menu Bar** as seen on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtBsD.png) screenshot.

Comment: To view image please click on link.

Answer (score 12):

CONTROL + SHIFT + P and execute command  "Tree View: Show"

Answer (score 4):

Same happened to me, I had to go into Packages and re-enable Tabs and Tree-View (both part of core).

Comment: This was the only answer that helped me. Crazy how this weird behavior is still happening two years later.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and Alt did not work for me. If you go into the config (mine was in users/{user_name}/.atom/config.cson), you will see a line for hidden tool bar, remove that line and restart Atom.

There is probably a value you can set it to besides "hidden" but I did not figure it out