# How to reopen sidebar in atom editor

Tags: react-native, atom-editor

I messed up something wrong, my side bar disappeared in atom. It is blank now, not showing files etc.  I checked this thread [Atom menu is missing. How do I re-enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29159379/atom-menu-is-missing-how-do-i-re-enable) but didn't work for me.

[image]

config.json

```
  "*":
    "atom-beautify":
      general:
        _analyticsUserId: "d356f20e-3597-4bb0-be87-5465af6abf2a"
    core:
      customFileTypes:
        "source.ini": [
          ".buckconfig"
          ".hgrc"
          ".flowconfig"
        ]
        "source.json": [
          ".arcconfig"
          "BUCK.autodeps"
        ]
        "source.python": [
          "BUCK"
        ]
      disabledPackages: [
        "tree-view"
      ]
      telemetryConsent: "limited"
    editor:
      fontSize: 21
    "exception-reporting":
      userId: "7c5d23fe-0d8c-4b29-9191-f439c2dca0f6"
    "ide-flow":
      flowPath: "/cygdrive/c/Users/ajaysaini/AppData/Roaming/npm/flow"
    nuclide:
      "nuclide-code-format":
        formatOnSave: true
      "nuclide-flow":
        canUseFlowBin: true
        warnOnNotInstalled: false
    "nuclide-format-js": {}
    "prettier-atom":
      formatOnSaveOptions:
        enabled: true
    welcome:
      showOnStartup: false
```

Comment: its just hidden I guess. Hover to the left side of the atom window. You should find a arrow (it will popup on left side while hovering). Click on that to get the treeview back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have disabled the [`tree-view`](https://atom.io/packages/tree-view) package. Go to Settings > Packages and scroll down to Core Packages, disabled ones will be at the bottom of the category. Enable it and relaunch Atom.

```
disabledPackages: [
  "tree-view"
]
```

Comment: Sometimes other packages conflict and do this automatically, such as `nuclide`. Correct answer though.

Comment: @G0dsquad those many times show an error notification. I was going that route until seeing the quoted hint.

Comment: Thanks. I went through one post where guy hinted same solution. What is happening for me - It is getting disabled on launching automatically after enabling it. I don't know why it is. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: @Williams have you the atom-project-viewer package? Try if disabling it reverts your issue. If that's not the case, you should, try to open dev-tools and look if there're some errors in the console tab. If that isn't the case, try to get help on the [atom discussion forums](https://discuss.atom.io)