# Atom menu is missing. How do I re-enable the tools-menu?

Tags: menu, atom-editor

It is similar situation and  similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29159379/287948), but there are no solution for my specific problem. I used mu Atom editor for see Markdown text (preview), it was at a kind of "Tools menu"... Working fine last months.

Now there are **no tools-menu**, and  no `alt+t`  or similar command to enable it... How to get back the tools-menu?

---

Atom v1.18.0 working in UBUNTU 16 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown preview is located under Menu Bar > Packages > Markdown Preview > Toggle Preview. You may also activate it with a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks @Loading, up-voting because is a good answer... About question, "tools" was a mistaking name, but no "tools" neither "Packages"  was there, no menu... I **reboot** and now I see "Packages" menu. So the question is also "how to get back the Packages menu?"

Comment: @PeterKrauss Do you mean that menu bar is not showing up? If pressing alt shows it temporarily then from menu bar choose View > Toggle Menu Bar. You can also write Toggle Menu Bar in command palette (ctrl+shift+P).